# HTML5 video and MP4 video format integration with SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, html5-video, mp4

My requirement is to upload video files to sharepoint and renders videos to html page and I have created Assets Library for uploading video files and uploaded one sample .mp4 file. But when I try to play video intersting to the page using built a custom visual webpart,and I am getting "MIME type" not supported error message in IE browser.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps:
I think you must enter the correct in IIS before using a particular file type, in this case `video/mp4`.

1. Go to All Programs > Administrative Tools and select Internet
   Information Services (IIS) Manager.
2. Select your project from left site.
3. Look for MIME type icon in the central panel and click on it.
4. You will see ACTIONS in the right panel. Enter .mp4 in File name extension and video/mp4 in MIME type and click OK.